# Static constexpr member of a template class different for each instance?

Tags: c++, templates

I was under the impression that static members of a class share their value between all instances of that class. My understanding seems to be lacking though, perhaps because of the inclusion of templates or `constexpr` in this example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

template <typename T, std::size_t maxSize>
class Foo
{
public:
    unsigned int getLen() {
        return containerLen;
    }
    
private:
    static constexpr std::size_t containerLen = maxSize + 1;
    std::array<T, containerLen> arr;
};

int main()
{
    Foo<int, 10> foo1;
    std::cout << foo1.getLen() << std::endl;
    
    Foo<int, 12> foo2;
    std::cout << foo2.getLen() << std::endl;
    std::cout << foo1.getLen() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Which gives the following output:

```
    11
    13
    11
```

I'm probably missing something obvious, but what is it that allows each instance of `Foo` to have a different value of `containerLen`?

Comment: That's because you have different and completely independent class instances of `Foo`, and each of them has it's own `static` members. Why would you expect them to be the same? `maxSize` is even a template parameter.

Comment: Hint: `TemplateType<Some Parameters>` is a completely different type from `TemplateType<Some Other Parameters>`

Comment: Every instantiation of a template is a separate class, so what's your question?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Foo<int, 10>` and `Foo<int, 12>` are *different classes* - they just share the same *template*. All instances of `Foo<int, 10>` will share the same `containerLen`, as will all instances of `Foo<int, 12>`; but the two classes will *not* share a common value.

Answer (score 4):

Your error is consider `Foo` a class.

It's a class **template**, so `Foo<int, 10>` and `Foo<int, 12>` are different classes.

So there is a `containerLen` for `Foo<int, 10>` and a *different* `containerLen` for `Foo<int, 12>`.

If you want a common static member for all class templates, you can insert it in a common base class.

The following is a simple example

```
#include <iostream>

struct Foo
 { static int value; };

int Foo::value = 0u;

template <typename T>
struct Bar : public Foo // <-- all Bar classes inherit the same value
{ };

int main()
 {
   Bar<int>  bi;
   Bar<long> bl;

   bi.value = 10;
   bl.value ++;

   std::cout << bi.value << std::endl; // print 11
   std::cout << bl.value << std::endl; // print 11
 }
```